android Geocoder onGeocode is executed by a UID different from the UID of my application
In my application, after locating the location, I retrieve the address through Geocoder and save it into the database via ContentProvider. The issue is that the result in onGeocode is executed in a thread with an owner different from the UID of my application, and consequently, I receive the error:
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.example.app.db.DataBaseProvider uri content://com.example.app/location from pid=0, uid=10129 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission().

Is this a bug in Android? I can't believe that my own application needs to request permission to write to its own database. The solution with
new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(() -> { //save to db }); 

doesn't suit me because I'm worried about other Android methods that may encounter this obvious bug. I can't possibly know all the methods in Google Android that have this obvious bug.
I tried the following, but the error persists:
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                startTimeoutTimer();
                geocoder.getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1, new Geocoder.GeocodeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGeocode(@NonNull List<Address> mList) {
                        int callingUid = Binder.getCallingUid();
                        String callingPackage = mContext.getPackageManager().getNameForUid(callingUid);
                        mContext.grantUriPermission(callingPackage , uri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
                       //callingPackage ="com.google.uid.shared:10129"
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(@Nullable String errorMessage) {
                    }
                });
}

